# How long should I wait until I see some XMR mined with Gupax?

Tags: mining, xmrig

I want to support Monero and installed Gupax linked to a GUI Monero Wallet.
P2Pool and XMRig are active.
I used it for the a few hours and don't see any XMR Mined.
Is it normal? did I forgot something?
[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> I used it for the a few hours and don't see any XMR Mined. Is it normal? did I forgot something?

From https://p2pool.io/#faq:

> **I have been mining for several hours and still got no rewards**?
>
> P2Pool doesn't work exactly like regular pools - there's no "pending
> balance" here. You need to find a pool share first and then wait for
> P2Pool to find a Monero block. You'll get a payout to your XMR wallet
> as soon as a block is found and you have shares in PPLNS window. It
> can take several days to a week to find a share if your hashrate is
> low. Type "status" command in P2Pool console or visit P2Pool observer
> to check your progress.